# Input Text Error With Clinet [Number] PyQt5 Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to receive a data from the user in my program in the form of a number, but I don't know why it gets an error

```
    self.InputTotal = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
    self.InputTotal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 20, 141, 31))
    self.InputTotal.setObjectName("InputTotal")
    chkinput = self.InputTotal.text()
```

## Need chkinput just number.

```
        if int(chkinput) == 0:
            ranger = 1000
        else:
            ranger = chkinput

       for i in range(ranger):
            self.btn_eth.clicked.connect(self.Generator)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use a QSpinBox instead of a QLIneEdit. It's much more convienient for the user, and it automatically validates the input. As it is, if the user enters a non-numeric value, you have to show an error-message or something.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is that when you run `if int(chkinput) == 0` all it does is check if the `chkinput` variable cast to an integer equals zero.  It doesn't actually convert `chkinput` value to an integer.

For that you would need to assign the converted value back to the variable name like: `chkinput = int(chkinput)`.

So currently when your `chkinput` doesn't equal 0, you are assigning a string value to the `ranger` variable in the `else` clause which will throw an error when you try to use it as a range.

You should also add some extra error checking as well so you don't run in to even more issues. For example, you can check that the text isn't  an empty string, then check if the contents is a number using the `.isdigit()` method, then if that returns true then you know it is safe to use the `int` constructor without it throwing an error.

```
chkinput = self.InputTotal.text()
if len(chkinput) > 0 and chkinput.strip().isdigit():
    chkinput = int(chkinput)
    if chkinput == 0:
        ranger = 1000
    else:
         ranger = chkinput
    for i in range(ranger):
        self.btn_eth.clicked.connect(self.Generator)
```